# PIG not reading file from hdfs when running from pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying  to load a file from hdfs using a pigscript

```
data = LOAD '/user/Z013W7X/typeahead/time_decayed_clickdata.tsv' using PigStorage('\t') as (keyword :chararray , search_count: double, clicks: double, cartadds: double);
```

the path mentioned above is hdfs path.
when I run the same script using pig grunt, it executes without any problem but the same code using a script shows the following problem:

> Input(s):
>   Failed to read data from "/user/Z013W7X/typeahead/time_decayed_clickdata.tsv"

This is the shell script I am using to call the pig script...

```
jar_path=/home_dir/z013w7x/workspace/tapipeline/Typeahead-APP/tapipeline/libs/takeygen-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
scripts_path=/home_dir/z013w7x/workspace/tapipeline/Typeahead-APP/tapipeline/pig_scripts/daily_running_scripts
dataset_path=hdfs://d-3zkyk02.target.com:8020/user/Z013W7X/typeahead
data_files=/user/Z013W7X/typeahead/data_files.zip#data
ngrams_gen_script=$scripts_path/generate_ngrams.pig
time_decayed_clickdata_file=$dataset_path/time_decayed_clickdata.tsv
all_suggestions_file=$results_path/all_suggestions.tsv
top_suggestions_file=$results_path/top_suggestions.tsv

pig -f $ngrams_gen_script -param "INPUT_TIME_DECAYED_CLICKDATA_FILE=$time_decayed_clickdata_file" -param "OUTPUT_ALL_SUGGESTIONS_FILE=$all_suggestions_file" -param "OUTPUT_TOP_SUGGESTIONS_FILE=$top_suggestions_file" -param "REGISTER=$jar_path" -param "INPUT_DATA_ARCHIVE=$data_files"
```

The pig script is as follows-

```
SET mapred.create.symlink yes
SET mapred.cache.archives $INPUT_DATA_ARCHIVE

register $REGISTER
click_data = LOAD '$INPUT_TIME_DECAYED_CLICKDATA_FILE' using PigStorage('\t') as (keyword :chararray , search_count: double, clicks: double, cartadds: double);
ordered_click_data = order click_data by search_count desc;
sample_data = LIMIT ordered_click_data 3000000;
mclick_data = foreach sample_data generate keyword, CEIL(search_count) as search_count, CEIL(clicks) as clicks, CEIL(cartadds) as cartadds;
fclick_data = filter mclick_data by (keyword is not null and search_count is not null and keyword != 'NULL' );

ngram_data = foreach fclick_data generate flatten(com.tgt.search.typeahead.takeygen.udf.NGramScore(keyword, search_count, clicks, cartadds))
 as (stemmedKeyword:chararray, keyword:chararray, dscore:double, isUserQuery:int, contrib:double, keyscore:chararray);

grouped_data = group ngram_data by stemmedKeyword;
agg_data = foreach grouped_data generate group, flatten(com.tgt.search.typeahead.takeygen.udf.StemmedKeyword(ngram_data.keyscore)) as keyword,
                                                                                                                 SUM(ngram_data.dscore) as ascore, SUM(ngram_data.isUserQuery) as isUserQuery, SUM(ngram_data.contrib) as contrib;
filter_queries = filter agg_data by isUserQuery > 0;
all_suggestions = foreach  filter_queries generate keyword, ascore;
ordered_suggestions = order all_suggestions by ascore desc;
top_suggestions = limit ordered_suggestions 200000;

rmf /tmp/all_suggestions
rmf $OUTPUT_ALL_SUGGESTIONS_FILE
rmf /tmp/top_suggestions
rmf $OUTPUT_TOP_SUGGESTIONS_FILE

store ordered_suggestions  into '/tmp/all_suggestions' using PigStorage('\t','-schema');
store top_suggestions  into '/tmp/top_suggestions' using PigStorage('\t','-schema');
cp /tmp/all_suggestions/part-r-00000 $OUTPUT_ALL_SUGGESTIONS_FILE
cp /tmp/top_suggestions/part-r-00000 $OUTPUT_TOP_SUGGESTIONS_FILE
```

Comment: how are you running your script?

Comment: I am running the script from a shell script

Comment: make sure that you are not running your pig script in local mode.

Comment: No, thats not the case....
It is having some problem in reading the input files..

Comment: can you try replacing "data_files=/user/Z013W7X/typeahead/data_files.zip#data" this with "data_files=hdfs://d-3zkyk02.target.com:8020/user/Z013W7X/typeahead/data_files.zip#data" ?

Comment: Looks to me like the grunt shell is somehow using a different hadoop config than when running via shell command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `hdfs://namenode_host:54310` before the input path. Try below.

```
data = LOAD 'hdfs://namenode_host:54310/user/Z013W7X/typeahead/time_decayed_clickdata.tsv' using PigStorage('\t') as (keyword :chararray , search_count: double, clicks: double, cartadds: double);
```

Comment: Try now. Updated. You need to add namenode host and port.

Comment: Is your path correct. Please check with ' hdfs dfs -ls'.

Comment: the same path is running when I am directly using it pig grunt.. only when I am using it in script , it is showing the problems..

Comment: what exactly you are running, can you paste that in the question.